# BroadcastReceiver for CONNECTIVITY_ACTION always returns null in intent.getExtras()

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, connectivity

Im trying to receive BroadcastMessages from CONNECTIVITY_ACTION:

```
    // register BroadcastReceiver on network state changes
    final IntentFilter mIFNetwork = new IntentFilter();
    mIFNetwork.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION); //"android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
    registerReceiver(mIRNetwork, mIFNetwork);
```

and receiver is:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mIRNetwork = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        android.util.Log.i(TAG,"mIRNetwork: Network State Received: "+intent.getAction());
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras!=null){
                android.util.Log.i(TAG,"mIRNetwork: ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED: "+extras.getString(ConnectivityManager.ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED));
                android.util.Log.i(TAG,"mIRNetwork: CONNECTIVITY_ACTION: "+extras.getString(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
                android.util.Log.i(TAG,"mIRNetwork: EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO: "+extras.getString(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO));
                android.util.Log.i(TAG,"mIRNetwork: EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY: "+extras.getString(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY));
                android.util.Log.i(TAG,"mIRNetwork: EXTRA_REASON: "+extras.getString(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON));

            }
        }
```

in short extras is always null. I thought that if i loose WiFi connection i should get EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY (cuz its the only way to Internet) or at least something from the list. But no luck. If i disconnect my WiFi AP receiver gets his message but with null extras. When i turn my WiFi back on once again receiver fires but no extras... Why is that? How to know that app lost any network connection? I thought its the way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can not get extra but you can get data by this way

```
private class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager
                .EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        NetworkInfo info1 = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager
                .EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        NetworkInfo info2 = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager
                .EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);
        String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        boolean failOver = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);
        Log.d("MY_TAG", "onReceive(): mNetworkInfo=" + info1 + " mOtherNetworkInfo = " +
                (info2 == null ? "[none]" : info2 + " noConn=" + noConnectivity));
    }
}
```

For more info see this

http://code.google.com/p/androidwisprclient/source/browse/trunk/src/com/joan/pruebas/NetworkConnectivityListener.java?r=2

Comment: `if(!action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))` can't understand this when the only action added to filter is CONNECTIVITY_ACTION?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar You can ignore condition to check action if you have registered only one action for connectivity.

Comment: In order to check if we have Internet connection, is it safe to just use "!intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false) "  ?

Answer (score 5):

[Dharmendras answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924190/1955202) is good. However, note that `EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO` is now deprecated (since Api Level 14) and the Android docs say the following:

> Since NetworkInfo can vary based on UID, applications should always obtain network information through `getActiveNetworkInfo()`.

That actually makes things very easy for us. You could reuse the connectivity check you probably did before and do something like this:

```
private class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        unregisterReceiver(this)
        checkConnection();
    }
}

private void checkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()
            .isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

<sub>Assuming you're inside the activity that registered the broadcast of course.</sub>

This also has the added benefit of following the best practices for only listening for the connectivity broadcast as briefly as possible, [outlined here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges) :)