# Android Broadcast receiver not working on app close

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I have created a broadcast receiver to listen for connectivity change events.
Receiver works perfectly when I minimize the app using home button.
But when I use back button to exit the app broadcast receiver stops listening for connectivity changes.
I searched for it and found that I should call broadcast receiver from a service but that too is not working on app close.
Here is my code for broadcast receiver with service.

Internet Service

```
 public class InternetService extends Service {

    NetworkChangeReceiver networkChangeReceiver;

    public InternetService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        networkChangeReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        registerReceiver(networkChangeReceiver, filter);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Broadcast receiver

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    boolean isConnected = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        isNetworkAvailable(context);

    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                if (info.isConnected()) {
                    if (!isConnected) {
                        isConnected = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.v("Internet", "Internet Connected");
                        hitDataService();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityForm.this, MyService.class);
                        startService(intent);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        isConnected = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to send some data to service even on app close and when mobile is connected to internet.
Is there any other way of getting same behaviour.

I also tried adding following lines in onCreateMethod() but still no luck

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getBaseContext(), NetworkChangeReceiver.class);
                                                    PackageManager pm = getBaseContext().getPackageManager();
                                                    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                                                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                                                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: your broadcast receiver is an inner class of an activity ?

Comment: yes it is an inner class

Comment: I would start moving it in a separate class or making it static

Comment: Are you force closing you app

Comment: no just doing backpress

Comment: I have now moved broadcast receiver to separate class

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the Sample Code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled) that successfully processes alarm events, even after the process has been terminated by DDMS.

You can check the implementation of Broadcast Receiver in above sample that works even after app close.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: In this example they are using alarm manager object and a pending indent . Can I use it for checking connectivity changes also??

Answer (score 0):

If You want to make the app listen for `NetworkChangeReceiver` broadcasts after you close the app, make sure you run `InternetService` before the app get closed.

Assuming your main activity is called `MainActivity` you can do like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InternetService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

For `NetworkChangeReceiver` [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924190/2626517) might be helpful.

Comment: this also didn't helped

Comment: this exception means that a constructor with no parameters must be implemented, check error for line number where this occurs to know which class makes the error.

Comment: yes I sorted out that error but calling service from onDestroy didn't helped

Comment: I think the service is started but `BroadcastReciver` is not working

Comment: yes it is not listening for events on app close
Service is working fine I have tested it before